# WhatsApp use only html to share url link by a descriptive text

Tags: html, share, href, whatsapp

I want to enable my website users to share the current web page url (stored in ViewBag.OgUrl) via WhatsApp.

The WhatsApp message should contain the *url title* (stored in ViewBag.OgTitle) which, when clicked, will open the url (stored in ViewBag.OgUrl).

This needs to be done by html without js.

The standard way is:

```
 @{
    var urlWhatsapp = "whatsapp://send?text=" + @ViewBag.OgUrl;
  }
```

And then simply:

```
 <a href="@urlWhatsapp" target="_blank">WhatsApp Share</a>
```

This works fine apart from the fact that the actual url is shared and not the title.

For example, a WhatsApp message contains the actual link http://example.org/ while I would like it to show in WhatsApp:

[First example](http://example.org/)

Edit: If one wants to get the title and the link just replace the code with:

```
  @{var urlWhatsapp = "whatsapp://send?text=" + @ViewBag.OgTitle + " - " + @ViewBag.OgUrl;}

<a class="fa fa-whatsapp" href="@urlWhatsapp" target="_blank"></a>
```

If one waits after the sharing, but before actually sending the message to the recipient, a clickable box appears above the original message (as would be for any whatsapp link with what is defined in the url - an image, text etc. according - see the example below)
[image]

Comment: did you found answer

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to share a link on WhatsApp the way you want to. You can only send a message with the full link like `http://example.org/` and WhatsApp will detect this as a link for you.

Comment: Yes, I use the standard way. I was not sure it was not possible to name the link.

Answer (score 1):

the question asked about an html based procedure (no js)

The answer is that at this time, it is possible to send text + a link to be identified by WhatsApp.

it is not possible to send only a title which, when clicked, will be linked to the url itself.

The syntax in the html is:

```
    @{var urlWhatsapp = "whatsapp://send?text=" + @ViewBag.OgTitle + " - " + @ViewBag.OgUrl;}

    <a class="fa fa-whatsapp" href="@urlWhatsapp" target="_blank"></a>
```

where the @ViewBag.OgTitle is the title and the @ViewBag.OgUrl is the full url (including http:// or https://)

Comment: How to create a message in whatsapp with a hyperlink in it. I want to give a name to hyperlink. I receive such messages via whatsapp.

Comment: I have edited the answer to the best analog I am aware of. If you apply this, and wait for a second or two after the sharing you will get above the original text with the link the description + some photo (if you applied it) and this is clickable to get to your link

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<a href="https://web.whatsapp.com/send?l=en&phone=+91 0000000000&text=I want to 
order a website" target="blank"></a>
```

Where `0000000000` will be your 10 digit mobile no. and text= will be your predefined message.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to send messages to Whatsapp from a link on your site.

The first one...

```
<a href="https://wa.me/5579XXXXXXXXX"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i> +55 (79) XXXXX-XXXX</a>
```

The second, with predefined text...

```
<a href="https://wa.me/5579XXXXXXXXX?text=I'm%20interested%20to%20know%20more%20about%20your%20job."><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i> +55 (79) XXXXX-XXXX</a>
```

- You don't need to put "+" (plus) in your number.
- To do spaces in the text, you need to use "%20" between words.